# Capture any event in socket.io

Tags: socket.io

In my socket.io application, I happen to have several events with similar handlers. Here is a simplified illustration:

```
  socket.on('event1', function (data) {
     print "1";
  });

  socket.on('event2', function (data) {
     print "2";
  });
```

etc.

Is there a way to write a single event handler, that will catch such events, and call a callback with the specific event name?  Maybe something like this:

```
  socket.on(function (event, data) {
     print event;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i have met the same problem as yours. By now socket.io didn't support this functionality.
In my project,i change my client code from 'socket.emit' to 'socket.send',and do the object serialization by myself.

Comment: Can you give an example of changing the client code from "emit" to "send", while keeping the different event types?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `socket.io-events` it does *exactly* what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
function foo(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
socket.on('event1', foo);
socket.on('event2', foo);
```

Comment: A. this is not really a single event handler... if there are many events, I will still need many handlers.
B. The function 'foo' does not know the type of event that triggered it.

Comment: Then I surely don't understand your question.  What's wrong with your original code?

Comment: Well there is a special 'message' event you can listen for, which captures all messages sent with send().  Try that.